# Getting value of key in array

Tags: php, arrays, key

how can i get the value of an key in array?
my array is like:

```
$array = array(
  array(key1 => "value1", key2 => "value2", key3 => "value3"),
  array(key1 => "value1", key2 => "value2", key3 => "value3"),
  array(key1 => "value1", key2 => "value2", key3 => "value3"),
  array(key1 => "value1", key2 => "value2", key3 => "value3")
);

foreach($array as $row) {
  $key1 = $row['key1'];
  $key2 = $row['key2'];
  $key3 = $row['key3'];
}
```

// so it should be possible to write e.g. echo $ke1, and then get the out value1 or echo $key2 and get the output: value 2 and so on...

how is this possible? hopefully someone understands me:)

best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
foreach($array as $row) {
    foreach($row as $key => $value) {
        // first iteration, $key == key1, $value = 'value1'
    }
}
```